# Converting String Array list to char array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and trying to learn conversion from char ArrayList to char array. I am having some hard time to convert this.

```
 List<Character> code = new ArrayList<Character>();
 code.add("A");
 code.add("B");
 code.add("C");
```

This will display as `[A, B, C]`. What I want to do is to convert this array list to `char[]` array.

What I tried was the following:

```
char[] list = null;
for(int i=0; i<code.size(); i++){
    list[i] = code.get(i);
    System.out.println(list[i]); // this has the error
}
```

The error I am getting is `java.lang.NullPointerException`. 
I searched online but I couldn't find a "better" solution. Most of them are a conversion from string to char or vice versa. Perhaps I am missing some important knowledge about this. 
Again, I am new to Java and any help will be appreciated!.

Comment: The `List` interface includes a `toArray` method that does this conversion for you.  Also, be careful about the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: you should refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-array-conversion-java-toarray-methods/

Comment: double quotes are wrong. It's supposed to be single. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `null pointer exception` because you initialized the char array to `null`. Instead, you would want to initialize it to a new char array size equal to that of the ArrayList like:

`char[] list = new char[code.size()];`

Here is how all the code would look.

```
List<Character> code = new ArrayList<Character>();
code.add("A");
code.add("B");
code.add("C");


char[] list = new char[code.size()]; // Updated code

for(int i=0; i<code.size(); i++){
    list[i] = code.get(i);
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `char[]` before using. something like

```
char[] list = new char[code.size()];
```

You are getting `NullPointerException` since the list variable is initialised with null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Null Pointer exception is due to initializing to null

```
  List<Character> code = new ArrayList<Character>();
        code.add('A');
        code.add('B');
        code.add('C');


        Character[] arr = new Character[code.size()];
        arr = code.toArray(arr);

        System.out.println(arr);
```